# Имя сохраняемой страницы php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Имеется код:

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen(date('Ymdhis').'-data.html', 'w'); 
$html = ""; 

foreach($_POST[data] as $data) { 
$html .= $data.PHP_EOL; 
} 

echo (fwrite($fp, $html)) ? "Сохранено" : "Не сохранено"; 

fclose($fp);
?>
```

JS+HTML

```
<div class="getcode">Наполняемый контент, другие div блоки</div>
<button>Получить и сохранить сожержимое</button>

<script>
    var button = document.querySelector("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", sendSave, false);

    function sendSave() {
        var data = document.querySelector(".getcode").innerHTML;

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("data", data);

        var XHR = "onload" in new XMLHttpRequest() ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;
        var xhr = new XHR();
        xhr.open('POST', 'save.php', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState !== 4) {
                return;
            }
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        };
        xhr.send(formData);
    }
</script>
```

Содержимое div блока сохраняется в файл на сервере по нажатию кнопки. Как реализовать чтобы при сохранении на странице еще через input передавать имя файла который сохранится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormData` третьим параметром принимает, как раз таки, имя файла которое будет отправлено серверу (USVString), когда Blob или File прошел проверку как второй параметр. Стандартное имя файла для Blob объектов это "blob".

Пример:

```
var formData = new FormData(); // Currently empty
formData.append('username', 'Chris');
formData.append('userpic', myFileInput.files[0], 'chris.jpg');
```

[Справка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

Соответственно значения инпута передаете третьим параметром и вроде как на этом всё. На сервере, соответственно, достаете.

---

Например инпут `<input type="text" id="test" value="myTextValue">`, достаем так:

```
var txtName = document.querySelector('#test').value;
```

Передаем:

```
var txtName = document.querySelector('YOUR_SELECTOR').value;
var formData = new FormData(); // Currently empty
formData.append('username', 'Chris');
formData.append('userfile', myFileInput.files[0], txtName);
```

Правда это что касается файлов..

Если вы передаете в значении строку, то тогда из инпута также надо добавить новый передаваемый параметр со своим ключом, но со значением из инпута, т.е.

```
var data = document.querySelector(".getcode").innerHTML;
var fileName = document.querySelector('YOUR_SELECTOR').value;

var formData = new FormData(); // Currently empty
formData.append('data ', data);
formData.append('fileName', fileName);
```

На сервере ловить переменную из `$_POST['fileName']`

---

**Итог**

HTML

```
<div class="getcode">Наполняемый контент, другие div блоки</div>
<button>Получить и сохранить сожержимое</button>
<input type="text" id="fileName" value="myTextValue">
```

JS

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", sendSave, false);

function sendSave() {
    var data = document.querySelector(".getcode").innerHTML;    
    var fileName = document.querySelector('#fileName').value;

    var formData = new FormData(); 
    formData.append('data', data);
    formData.append('fileName', fileName);

    var XHR = "onload" in new XMLHttpRequest() ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;
    var xhr = new XHR();
    xhr.open('POST', 'save.php', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState !== 4) {
            return;
        }
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

PHP

```
$fp = fopen($_POST['fileName'], 'w'); // $fp = fopen($_POST['fileName'].'-data.html', 'w');
$html = $_POST['data'].PHP_EOL;    

echo (fwrite($fp, $html)) ? "Сохранено" : "Не сохранено";

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: можете помочь с модимфикацией моего кода?, я не совсем понял что и как применить, инпут как связать? если его прописать?

Comment: @Павел написал. но это вроде стандарт

Comment: не работает ибо form data это вообще другая переменная. Имя создается этой строкой  $fp = fopen(date('Ymdhis').'-data.html', 'w'); . Вот как в эту строку поместить <input type="text" id="test" value="myTextValue"> это значение,

Comment: @Павел ммм. т.к. вы передаете строку, а не файл, значит достаточно из инпута также добавить новый передаваемый параметр со своим ключом, но со значением из инпута (смотри внизу ответа)

Comment: не получается, не работает. переолопатил весь код. Помогите в код к вопросу встроить пожалуйста(

Comment: @Павел в коде вопроса я вообще не вижу инпута

Comment: не работает, инпут я сам уже потом добавил, вы можете на примере модификации моего кода показать рабочий пример?

Comment: @Павел смотри..